# New computed column replicating SUMIFS from excel

Tags: r, sumifs

I have a data frame (df) as follows:

```
>date       fx      mkt_val
>03/01/2016 AUD     50
>03/01/2016 AUD     75
>03/01/2016 USD     100
>03/01/2016 USD     150
>03/02/2016 AUD     50
>03/02/2016 AUD     500
>03/02/2016 USD     150
>03/02/2016 USD     275
```

I want to be able effectively replicate the SUMIFS function in excel, so that I get a new column that contains the sum of each fx value for each date. Such that the output would look as follows:

```
>date       fx  mkt_val sumifs
>03/01/2016 AUD   50    125
>03/01/2016 AUD   75    125
>03/01/2016 USD   100   250
>03/01/2016 USD   150   250
>03/02/2016 AUD   50    550
>03/02/2016 AUD   500   550
>03/02/2016 USD   150   425
>03/02/2016 USD   275   425
```

Any points to the right direction or code would help! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `ave`.  No packages are used.

```
transform(DF, sumif = ave(mkt_val, date, fx, FUN = sum))
```

giving:

```
        date  fx mkt_val sumif
1 03/01/2016 AUD      50   125
2 03/01/2016 AUD      75   125
3 03/01/2016 USD     100   250
4 03/01/2016 USD     150   250
5 03/02/2016 AUD      50   550
6 03/02/2016 AUD     500   550
7 03/02/2016 USD     150   425
8 03/02/2016 USD     275   425
```

**Note:** the input in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "date       fx      mkt_val
03/01/2016 AUD     50
03/01/2016 AUD     75
03/01/2016 USD     100
03/01/2016 USD     150
03/02/2016 AUD     50
03/02/2016 AUD     500
03/02/2016 USD     150
03/02/2016 USD     275"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and scaled up nicely. Thank you! @G. Grothendieck

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr ibraries. Please (in general) provide data using dput or other directly reproducible way, to make it easier to reproduce.

```
df <- read.delim(text="
date fx mkt_val
03/01/2016 AUD 50
03/01/2016 AUD 75
03/01/2016 USD 100
03/01/2016 USD 150
03/02/2016 AUD 50
03/02/2016 AUD 500
03/02/2016 USD 150
03/02/2016 USD 275
", sep=" ", row.names=NULL)

library(dplyr)

# summarize
summary <- df %>% 
  group_by(date, fx) %>%
  summarize(sumifs = sum(mkt_val)) 

# join back to the original
result <- df %>% 
  inner_join(summary, by=c("date", "fx"))
```

result

```
        date  fx mkt_val sumifs
1 03/01/2016 AUD      50    125
2 03/01/2016 AUD      75    125
3 03/01/2016 USD     100    250
4 03/01/2016 USD     150    250
5 03/02/2016 AUD      50    550
6 03/02/2016 AUD     500    550
7 03/02/2016 USD     150    425
8 03/02/2016 USD     275    425
```